# How to lookbehind with non-fixed width in regex

Tags: regex

I have the following text:

> "Requesting to change config.fix.some.value to 2000"

I'm currently wanting to parse the value, 2000, after the 'to' identifier, but only after config.fix.some.value.

The config.fix.some.value is of unfixed length.

I'm trying to use lookbehind regex and can't seem to get around this.

My current regex query: `(?<=(\w+[.\w]+\sto))`

Comment: Your current pattern decribes a 0-length string immediately following the first instance of the word `to`. You probably want `(?<=\w+(?:\.\w+)+\sto\s*)\d+` instead

Comment: Where are you using the regex? How? Within which regex method/function?

Answer (score 2):

Since you need fixed length for the lookbehind, then extract it with group tag instead:

```
\w+[.\w]+\sto\s(\d+)
```

Comment: GOAT. Thanks for this - it works. Although I dont fully understand group yet as I'm still trying to learn regex, this gives me a good idea of what should be done in the future

Comment: Np. Here is a great tool for trying out different regex: https://regex101.com/

Comment: How would one capture either group of digits or text? I have this so far but doesn't seem to be working: \w+[.\w]+\sto\s[(\d+)|(\w+)]

Comment: \w covers the follwing characters: 'A-Z, a-z, 0-9 and _', meaning '\w' will match both digit and text. Therefor \w is the same thing as: [a-zA-Z_0-9]

Comment: There are 2 groups for match. Are we able to refine the regex any further or is this the downside: "Change the config value of config.change.some.value to 2048 in order to see if this works"

Comment: If you want to match the value and validate if it consist of digits or being  words ([a-zA-Z_0-9]+), then I thin you need to use two regex to make a difference between them.